# Visualforce align text to right of radio button

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, apex

I have some simple code to display a list as radiobuttons:

```
<apex:selectRadio value="{!q.option}" layout="pageDirection">
      <apex:selectOptions value="{!q.options}"/>
</apex:selectRadio>
```

My problem is that the texts of the options are aligned below the radio buttons:

```
O
option1

O
option2
```

When what I need is:

```
O option1
O option2
```

I suspect CSS is the issue but I can't access it. Is there a way to overwrite that CSS to fix this? or any other option?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your VF page, just below the page tag, you can specify a style section and add a style class on your component just like in .NET. You can also have site wide CSS files, but I don't think that's what you are asking here.

```
<apex:page>
<style type="text/css">
    .italicText { font-style: italic; }
</style>
<apex:outputText styleClass="italicText" value="This is kind of fancy."/>
</apex:page>
```

For more info: https://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_styling_custom.htm